# Audio problems in nativescript app on iOS

Tags: nativescript

I have a nativescript-app that uses text-to-speech functionality (`@nativescript-community/texttospeech`).
This is working fine so far.

Now, I open a modal-view with the `@nstudio/camera-plus` plugin that enables the user to capture a photo.

After closing the camera-view, the audio of the text-to-speech is only half as loud as before.

Is the camera messing up the audio-settings? And if so, how can I avoid that?

Nativescript 8.1
texttospeech 3.0.3
camera-plus 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find the cause for this, but at least a workaround.

I put this above every audio-related task:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategoryWithOptionsError( AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker);
```

That sets the volume back to full.